# How to split tasklist at tasks page of Inno Setup into multiple columns?

Tags: inno-setup

Is it possible splitting tasklist at *Select Additional Tasks* page like in the picture below?

*Example:*

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, Inno Setup does not support multi-column (check) list boxes.

---

But you can easily implement a custom page with look and feel of the standard *"Select Additional Tasks"* page, just with three separate check list boxes. Then, you can use the [`Check` parameter](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptcheck) instead of the [`Tasks` parameter](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=componentstasksparams) to bind custom tasks to sections likes `Files`, `Icons`, etc.

```pascal
[Files]
Source: "FileForSubTask_0_1.txt"; DestDir: "{app}"; Check: GetCustomTask(0, 1);
Source: "FileForSubTask_0_2.txt"; DestDir: "{app}"; Check: GetCustomTask(0, 2);
...

[Code]

var
  CustomSelectTasksPage: TWizardPage;
  TasksLists: array of TNewCheckListBox;

const
  TaskColumns = 3;

procedure InitializeWizard();
var
  TasksList: TNewCheckListBox;
  I, GapWidth: Integer;
begin
  CustomSelectTasksPage :=
    CreateCustomPage(
      wpSelectTasks, SetupMessage(msgWizardSelectTasks),
      SetupMessage(msgSelectTasksDesc));

  SetArrayLength(TasksLists, TaskColumns);

  GapWidth := ScaleX(16);

  for I := 0 to TaskColumns - 1 do
  begin
    TasksList := TNewCheckListBox.Create(WizardForm);
    TasksList.Width :=
      (CustomSelectTasksPage.SurfaceWidth - (GapWidth * (TaskColumns - 1))) div
        TaskColumns; 
    TasksList.Left := I * (TasksList.Width + GapWidth);
    TasksList.Top := 0;
    TasksList.Height := WizardForm.InnerNotebook.Height - ScaleY(8);

    TasksList.BorderStyle := bsNone;
    TasksList.Color := clBtnFace;
    TasksList.ShowLines := False;
    TasksList.MinItemHeight := ScaleY(22);
    TasksList.ParentColor := True;
    TasksList.WantTabs := True;

    TasksList.Parent := CustomSelectTasksPage.Surface;

    TasksLists[I] := TasksList;
  end;

  TasksLists[0].AddCheckBox('TASK 0:0', '', 0, False, True, False, False, nil);
  TasksLists[0].AddCheckBox('Subtask 0:1', '', 1, False, True, False, False, nil);
  TasksLists[0].AddCheckBox('Subtask 0:2', '', 1, False, True, False, False, nil);

  TasksLists[1].AddCheckBox('TASK 1:0', '', 0, False, True, False, False, nil);
  TasksLists[1].AddCheckBox('Subtask 1:1', '', 1, False, True, False, False, nil);
  TasksLists[1].AddCheckBox('Subtask 1:2', '', 1, False, True, False, False, nil);

  TasksLists[2].AddCheckBox('TASK 2:0', '', 0, False, True, False, False, nil);
  TasksLists[2].AddCheckBox('Subtask 2:1', '', 1, False, True, False, False, nil);
  TasksLists[2].AddCheckBox('Subtask 2:2', '', 1, False, True, False, False, nil);
end;


function GetCustomTask(ListIndex: Integer; TaskIndex: Integer): Boolean;
begin 
  Result := TasksLists[ListIndex].Checked[TaskIndex];
end;
```

[image: Custom tasks page]