# Inno Setup - How to increase the separation between all the components of the component list?

Tags: inno-setup

I am using this code: [Long descriptions on Inno Setup components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10867087/long-descriptions-on-inno-setup-components/41649079?noredirect=1#comment70556564_41649079). How to increase the separation between all the components of the component list?

Example:

[image]

And i want to see this:

[image]

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I think he mean he wants to enter a new line after each component name in component list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's [`TNewCheckListBox.MinItemHeight`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptclasses&anchor=TNewCheckListBox) property that you can use to make a line in the checklist box higher, effectively increasing the spacing.

But problem is that setting the property does not affect existing items. And at the time the [`InitializeWizard`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=InitializeWizard) is called, the `WizardForm.ComponentsList` is populated already.

What you can do is to programmatically change each item caption to trigger re-measuring of the item. Simple appending of a space will do (you can even strip it after the fact, if you wish).

```pascal
procedure InitializeWizard();
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  { Change line height }
  WizardForm.ComponentsList.MinItemHeight := ScaleY(26);

  { Trigger re-measuring of component items }
  for I := 0 to WizardForm.ComponentsList.Items.Count - 1 do
  begin
    WizardForm.ComponentsList.ItemCaption[I] :=
      WizardForm.ComponentsList.ItemCaption[I] + ' ';
  end;
end;
```

[image]

---

Or you can completely give up on the built-in components mechanism and build your own components-like page using plain checkboxes. You can layout those any way you like.

For an example of implementing a custom components page, see

- [Inno Setup - Create a dynamic list of components/types from external source (file or folder contents)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37931971/850848)

Or similar questions for creating custom task pages:

- [How to split tasklist at tasks page of Inno Setup into multiple columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37886178/850848)
- [How to build a Treeview design (a task group with tasks nesting hierarchy) using Inno Setup?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40743335/850848)