# How to make work the new added checkboxes with the tasks?

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I have added new checkboxes to my inno setup tasks page but i dont know how to make them work with the tasks, i want them to work with the [Tasks] zone in the script.

```
[Tasks]
Name: "Newcheckboox1"; Description: "Newcheckbox1"; MinVersion: 0.0,5.0
Name: "Newcheckboox2"; Description: "Newcheckbox2"; MinVersion: 0.0,5.0
other tasks checkboxes here.........
```

Here an image:

[image]

Here the code generated when the checkboxes are added:

```
[Code]
{ RedesignWizardFormBegin } // Don't remove this line!
// Don't modify this section. It is generated automatically.
var
  NewGroupBox1: TNewGroupBox;
  NewCheckBox1: TNewCheckBox;
  NewCheckBox2: TNewCheckBox;
  NewCheckBox3: TNewCheckBox;
  NewGroupBox2: TNewGroupBox;
  NewCheckBox4: TNewCheckBox;
  NewCheckBox5: TNewCheckBox;
  NewGroupBox3: TNewGroupBox;
  NewCheckBox6: TNewCheckBox;
  NewCheckBox7: TNewCheckBox;
  NewCheckBox8: TNewCheckBox;

procedure RedesignWizardForm;
begin
  with WizardForm.SelectTasksLabel do
  begin
    Visible := False;
    Left := ScaleX(392);
  end;

  { NewGroupBox1 }
  NewGroupBox1 := TNewGroupBox.Create(WizardForm);
  with NewGroupBox1 do
  begin
    Parent := WizardForm.SelectTasksPage;
    Left := ScaleX(0);
    Top := ScaleY(0);
    Width := ScaleX(145);
    Height := ScaleY(238);
    Caption := 'NewGroupBox1';
  end;

  { NewCheckBox1 }
  NewCheckBox1 := TNewCheckBox.Create(WizardForm);
  with NewCheckBox1 do
  begin
    Parent := NewGroupBox1;
    Left := ScaleX(8);
    Top := ScaleY(16);
    Width := ScaleX(97);
    Height := ScaleY(17);
    Caption := 'NewCheckBox1';
  end;

  { NewCheckBox2 }
  NewCheckBox2 := TNewCheckBox.Create(WizardForm);
  with NewCheckBox2 do
  begin
    Parent := NewGroupBox1;
    Left := ScaleX(8);
    Top := ScaleY(40);
    Width := ScaleX(97);
    Height := ScaleY(17);
    Caption := 'NewCheckBox2';
  end;

  { NewCheckBox3 }
  NewCheckBox3 := TNewCheckBox.Create(WizardForm);
  with NewCheckBox3 do
  begin
    Parent := NewGroupBox1;
    Left := ScaleX(8);
    Top := ScaleY(64);
    Width := ScaleX(97);
    Height := ScaleY(17);
    Caption := 'NewCheckBox3';
  end;

  NewCheckBox1.TabOrder := 0;
  NewCheckBox2.TabOrder := 1;
  NewCheckBox3.TabOrder := 2;

  { NewGroupBox2 }
  NewGroupBox2 := TNewGroupBox.Create(WizardForm);
  with NewGroupBox2 do
  begin
    Parent := WizardForm.SelectTasksPage;
    Left := ScaleX(152);
    Top := ScaleY(0);
    Width := ScaleX(265);
    Height := ScaleY(97);
    Caption := 'NewGroupBox2';
  end;

  { NewCheckBox4 }
  NewCheckBox4 := TNewCheckBox.Create(WizardForm);
  with NewCheckBox4 do
  begin
    Parent := NewGroupBox2;
    Left := ScaleX(8);
    Top := ScaleY(16);
    Width := ScaleX(97);
    Height := ScaleY(17);
    Caption := 'NewCheckBox4';
  end;

  { NewCheckBox5 }
  NewCheckBox5 := TNewCheckBox.Create(WizardForm);
  with NewCheckBox5 do
  begin
    Parent := NewGroupBox2;
    Left := ScaleX(8);
    Top := ScaleY(40);
    Width := ScaleX(97);
    Height := ScaleY(17);
    Caption := 'NewCheckBox5';
  end;

  NewCheckBox4.TabOrder := 0;
  NewCheckBox5.TabOrder := 1;

  { NewGroupBox3 }
  NewGroupBox3 := TNewGroupBox.Create(WizardForm);
  with NewGroupBox3 do
  begin
    Parent := WizardForm.SelectTasksPage;
    Left := ScaleX(152);
    Top := ScaleY(96);
    Width := ScaleX(265);
    Height := ScaleY(142);
    Caption := 'NewGroupBox3';
  end;

  { NewCheckBox6 }
  NewCheckBox6 := TNewCheckBox.Create(WizardForm);
  with NewCheckBox6 do
  begin
    Parent := NewGroupBox3;
    Left := ScaleX(16);
    Top := ScaleY(24);
    Width := ScaleX(97);
    Height := ScaleY(17);
    Caption := 'NewCheckBox6';
  end;

  { NewCheckBox7 }
  NewCheckBox7 := TNewCheckBox.Create(WizardForm);
  with NewCheckBox7 do
  begin
    Parent := NewGroupBox3;
    Left := ScaleX(16);
    Top := ScaleY(48);
    Width := ScaleX(97);
    Height := ScaleY(17);
    Caption := 'NewCheckBox7';
  end;

  { NewCheckBox8 }
  NewCheckBox8 := TNewCheckBox.Create(WizardForm);
  with NewCheckBox8 do
  begin
    Parent := NewGroupBox3;
    Left := ScaleX(16);
    Top := ScaleY(72);
    Width := ScaleX(97);
    Height := ScaleY(17);
    Caption := 'NewCheckBox8';
  end;

  NewCheckBox6.TabOrder := 0;
  NewCheckBox7.TabOrder := 1;
  NewCheckBox8.TabOrder := 2;

  NewGroupBox1.TabOrder := 2;
  NewGroupBox2.TabOrder := 3;
  NewGroupBox3.TabOrder := 4;

{ ReservationBegin }
  // This part is for you. Add your specialized code here.

{ ReservationEnd }
end;
// Don't modify this section. It is generated automatically.
{ RedesignWizardFormEnd } // Don't remove this line!

procedure InitializeWizard();
begin
  RedesignWizardForm;
end;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot *"make them work with `Tasks`"*. That does not make sense. The only purpose of `Tasks` is to automatically create the checkboxes on the *"Select Additional Tasks"* page. As you create the checkboxes programmatically, there's nothing that `Tasks` will give you on top of that.

If you want to use your custom checkboxes *as* `Tasks`, use [`Check` parameter](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptcheck), instead of `Tasks`.

```pascal
[Files]
Source: "MyProg.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; Check: IsCustomTask1Selected

[Code]

var
  NewCheckBox1: TNewCheckBox;

function IsCustomTask1Selected: Boolean;
begin
  Result := NewCheckBox1.Checked;
end;
```

---

For a complete solution, see [How to split tasklist at tasks page of Inno Setup into multiple columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37886178/850848)

It works with the latest version of proper Inno Setup, with no need for an obsolete custom build of Inno Setup of doubtful origin.

---

Side notes:

- I'd recommend you to use `TNewCheckListBox`, instead of `TNewGroupBox` with individual checkboxes.
- 5.5.1 is very old version that suffers many security issues.

Answer (score 0):

Add a method for **OnClickCheck** event,

```
procedure InitializeWizard;
begin
    WizardForm.TasksList.OnClickCheck := @TasksListClickCheck
end;
```

Then implement **TasksListClickCheck** method,

```
procedure TasksListClickCheck(Sender: TObject);
begin
    /** Do whatever you want here **/
end;
```