# Components on multiple pages of Inno Setup installer

Tags: installation, inno-setup

I have a modpack with many `[Components]` and I wonder
whether there is a possibility to split them into multiple pages with the transition using the "Next" button.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible.

But you can implement a custom page with look and feel of the standard *"Select components"* page for the additional set of components.

Then, you can use the [`Check` parameter](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptcheck) instead of the [`Components` parameter](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=componentstasksparams) to bind the additional components from the custom page to sections likes `Files`, `Icons`, etc.

For a similar question, see [How to split tasklist at tasks page of Inno Setup into multiple columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37886178/850848)